# "Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage)" when trying to Bulk Insert in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, excel, csv, etl

I am trying to run the following:

```
BULK INSERT nashvilleHousing 
FROM 'C:\Users\Bruce\Downloads\Nashville Housing Data for Data Cleaning (2).csv'
WITH (
      FIRSTROW = 2, 
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
     );
```

To insert the following CSV data:

[image: I have attached screenshots of the source csv file.]

[image: Apologies if this appears somewhat messy.]

I get the following repeating error:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 4 (SalePrice).

This extends downwards to all rows in the original file (so row 3, column 4; row 4, column 4; etc....)

I have tried changing ROWTERMINATOR and FIELDTERMINATOR, and scanning the source data for errors. No luck.

Comment: images are bad, as they aren't god to read. And what ios the create table ?

Comment: Images are snips of the raw csv file opened via notepad. Much more clear upon clicking them. Not sure I understand the second question.

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2018** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 in the works  - take your pick!

Comment: @sysbruce  please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query even when someone wants to help nobpdy can

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you actually using? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73667315/edit) your question to include the output of `SELECT @@VERSION`.

Comment: It looks like you're dealing with RFC 4180-style CSV files, where the field data can contain commas `,` quotes `"` and line breaks... when escaped correctly. Have you read the `BULK INSERT` documentation yet, in particular the [`FORMAT='CSV'` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#format--csv)? You'll need SQL Server 2017 or later to read these files via `BULK INSERT`, otherwise use an external process like a PowerShell script.

Comment: @nbk I appreciate your links. As to whether or not you are actually correct, that remains to be seen. The tenor is unnecessary.

Comment: Question edited with correct version info. Copy/pasted output is as follows: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 22000: ) (Hypervisor)